# The hangman game backward #8

Tags: riddle, knowledge, english, language, letters

Hangman game backward #8 - guess what was the question:

fill in "d" - It does something horrible to the sand and stones, but it did the opposite to us.
fill in "f" - To some it's rapidly dangerous, others it's steady dangerous.
fill in "p" - It's from a drop of water, it's also from the American Beauty.

Again, your answer can be in the form of:

> The question was: _ p p l e

First answer that fully explained each line will be accepted, enjoy!

Comment: Something that came to my mind is: _art :D

Comment: @manshu that fits line 2 pretty well I've to say, others not so much haha

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think it is

> ri_ _le

fill in "d" - It does something horrible to the sand and stones, but it did the opposite to us.

> Riddle means 'to pierce with many holes' and we know what holes do. But here riddles are amazing. OP meant that riddle separates stones and sand, but bind us here in SE.

fill in "f" - To some it's rapidly dangerous, others it's steady dangerous.

> Riffle means 'a rocky or shallow part of a stream or river where the water flows brokenly'. A fast flowing water is dangerous. It's even more dangerous when it's rocky and cold.

fill in "p" - It's from a drop of water, it's also from the American Beauty.

> Ripple of water. American Beauty (album) by 'Grateful Dead' had a song named "[Ripple](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ripple_(song))".

All credit goes to my dictionary. :)

Comment: Re: the second answer. That's not how it's spelled.

Comment: @Bachrach44 thanks...I changed it accordingly.

Comment: @manshu was meant to say riddle separates stones and sand, but bind us here in SE, but I'll accept the answer